# Car jerking, losing power, stalled and won’t start

Tags: subaru

I was driving down the highway and my car started lurching and losing speed. I drove 2 exits down to my turn off with my car losing acceleration and when I came to a stop my car stalled and will turn over but not start. What could this be a sign of?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What is the year/model/engine of the car? When you turn the key to the on position, do you hear a *whrrrrr*ing sound from somewhere in the back of the car (fuel pump)?

Comment: Possible failed fuel pump.